# Custom FOSUserBundle Login Template using Bootstrap

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap, twig, fosuserbundle

I've installed Symfony2, FOS User Bundle and Twitter Bootstrap.

Then I setup the /app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig template to override FOSUserBundle to use my site template.

It all works if I have a link to /login on the homepage.

Now I want to implement a template like the [hero template](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html) where the login form is part of the main template.

The closest I've got is to use this in the main template:

```
{% render controller("FOSUserBundle:Security:login") %}
```

I can override the layout html to not extend main template, but this removes all styling from /login

Any ideas how I can handle both scenarios?

Comment: FOSUserBundle's documentation contains a chaper Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Templates: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard Miller's post has helped me achieve what I was trying to do.

http://richardmiller.co.uk/2013/02/18/symfony2-ajax-and-full-page-templates/

```
{% extends app.request.attributes.get('partial')
     ? '::ajax-layout.html.twig'
     : '::full-layout.html.twig' %}
```

I couldn't get  app.request.partial to work, and decided choosing based on xmlRequest wasn't ideal.

Answer (score 13):

You were almost there :)

you can include the login form in any other template using the render function.

```
{% render controller("FOSUserBundle:Security:login") %}
```

... you just have to create **app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html.twig** and ommit the wrapping `{% block fos_user_content %}` found in FOSUserBundle's [login.html.twig](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig) in order to have it return the form directly:

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error|trans }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

    <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />

    <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />

    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
    <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</label>

    <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" />
</form>
```

Then adjust it to fit your template.

Comment: thats great for putting it at the top, but when a user puts in an incorrect password sees the login form without styling

Comment: @nifr Excuse me, but I don't like this method. It's a solution from [tag:symfony]'s core, but what is the reason to prefer a hand written `template` to a *atomic* form type `class` ?

Comment: @cept0 - honestly i don't know why FOSUserBundle's registration-form is a form-type while the login-form is hardcoded into the template. you're right that this ain't the usual symfony-way ... I guess it's designed like that due to the fact that a hardcoded form allows easier inclusion into other templates ... you don't need to pass a variable containing the form to every view for rendering it ... but that's just a suggestion :)

Comment: Just one thing/ For the translations don't forget to tell the app to search them in FOSUserBundle - Eg: `{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}`